# How to load external forms and pages (php) using jQuery and PHP (.load() perhaps )?? Details are given below

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-load

I'm using PHP for my web project. The web pages I have created contains TABS control using jQuery. The TAB CONTENT has some FORMS, TABLES and TEXT etc..

The BEHAVIOR I want to achieve such that,

after user entered data to a form (and after successful validation), data in that form should passed to some PHP pages and based on the results TAB CONTENT (same tab) should be loaded with NEW FORMS and TABLES etc...

I want to achieve such a behavior for my WEB BASED PHP PROJECT. I'm NEW to jQuesry so please give any CODE EXAMPLES, LINKS TO TUTORIALS and REFERENCES etc...

Please help me to complete my Project successfully.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the question correctly, after registration you must load all your data, with forms, tables etc.

in your some.php file (which you call in your ajax request) you must generate your page.

```
some.php:

<?
echo "<table><tr><td> ..... </td>";
anything here...
?>
```

let's assume the content of tab must be in `<div id="content">` tag.

you just must write:

```
$("#content").html(data);
```

where data is responce from ajax request.